# How to use Context in android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-context

```
WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Why the `context` was used here?

Can any one explain?

Comment: for nonactivity and non-fragment class, they don't have context object which is required for many operations. so that's why you have to pass the context.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: so, just search  google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context)

> `Context` is the global information about an application environment.
>   This is an `abstract` class whose implementation is provided by the
>   `Android` system. It allows access to application-specific resources and
>   classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as
>   launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

If you want to use the `WIFI_SERVICE` which is a **application-specific resource**
you have to use the `context` to retrieve the resource.

If you are inside activities or fragments, then you can call `getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)` directly without using the `context` object because activities and fragments inherits from `Context` class.

But if you are in a non `Activity` or `Fragment` class then you have to pass the context object from the activity or fragment  (with constructors or setters) to that class in order to get application specific resources.

An example

```
public class AnyClass{

    private Context context;

    public AnyClass(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    ...

    WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: How can I use context for hotspot?

Comment: @pradeep Do you want to turn on or turn off wifi hotspot programatically?